# Types field in package.json for browser and main field

Tags: typescript, package.json

I created a library to be used in node and the browser.

The `package.json` file has the `main` and `browser` fields for that, which works fine.

But, the typings of the the node and browser version differ and there is only one `types` field.

How to get the right typings for both versions?

Comment: You can create a file which exports all types. e.g. create `./src/typings.ts` exporting both browser and server types and then point the `typings` field in `package.json` to `lib/typings.d.ts`

Answer (score 1):

Did alot of digging on this question as well, as far as I can tell by the time you need to split the types into browser/server it's time to make them separate packages.

Comment: Yes, I have come to that conclusion as well! It's understandable, but too bad you have to maintain an extra package for just slightly different types.

Comment: Sadly this does not work if it's an isomorphic package that by definition merges browser and server functionality..